# Log4j2 Migration: LocationInfo class is missing

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2

I'm migrating a large application from Log4j 1 to Log4j 2 following the guide of [Apache](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/migration.html). I came across the usage of Log4j1's [LocationInfo](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-1.2-api/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/spi/LocationInfo.html) class and now I'm not sure how to adjust the code to fit Log4j2. I checked the Log4j2 API and Implementation for a class with that name. Unfortunately without any success. Furthermore this problem is not mentioned by the guide or anywhere else I checked on the site. Anyone has an idea how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

A `LocationInfo` class is not used in Log4j 2.x Core, since the standard Java [`StackTraceElement`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StackTraceElement.html) is used instead. Of course it is still present in the Log4j 1.x Bridge (cf. [javadoc](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-1.2-api/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/spi/LocationInfo.html)).

To retrieve the `StackTraceElement`, just call [`LogEvent#getSource()`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/LogEvent.html#getSource--).

Be aware that retrieving location information is an expensive operation, therefore it is performed lazily if needed. `AsyncLogger`s by default don't retrieve it.